# Non Clustered Covering Index Column Selection Rules

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table with around 19 columns which contains reasonable large amount of data and is primarily being queried to retrieve data using select statements based on different where clause. Since this table is primarily queried to get data, I thought about creating Non Clustered indexes based on the different where clauses getting used in the queries. Also, all the get queries returns all the columns in the table as part of the select list. Based on the information above, I have two questions for selecting the indexes:

1. let us assume that we have the following SPs which queries as:

   ```
   where [col_a] = {value} and [col_b] = {value}

         [col_b] = {value} and [col_a] = {value}

         [col_a] = {value} and [col_c] = {value} and [col_d] = {value}

         [col_a] = {value} and [col_c] = {value}
   ```

   I have created the following Non Clustered indexes on the table as

   [col_a] and [col_b]   -->  Would the first SP still use this index as the
                              orders are reversed

   [col_a] and [col_c] and [col_d]   -->  Would the last SP use this index
                                          as the first two columns match with order

   Also, should we go ahead and try to define Non Clustered indexes based on the filter/join clauses for the get SPs on a table?
2. Since the select list in all the SPs return the entire list of columns, I added all the columns of the table as included columns in the Non Clustered indexes(covering index) to avoid bookmark lookups. Is this approach correct? What are the space implications in this case since we are storing all the table columns as part of the index definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [col_a] and [col_b]
>   *Would the first SP still use this index as
>   the orders are reversed*

Yes - if you specify **both** columns, and your index contains those two columns as the first two in its list of columns, then the index can be used, and the order is not important.

If you have an index `(col_a, col_b)`, it can be used if you specify:

- just `col_a`
- both `col_a` and `col_b` (order is irrelevant)

but it **cannot** be used for a query that specifies just `col_b` (but not `col_a`). In order to be considered for use, the n left-most columns (n >= 1) must be used/defined - in any order.

> [col_a] and [col_c] and [col_d]
>   *Would the last SP use this index
>   as the first two columns match with order*

Yes - as I mentioned above, if the n left-most columns are used, the index can be considered, so if your specify the first two of a total of three - you're fine.

Word of warning: just because you specify the right columns doesn't necessarily mean that index will actually be used in the end. The query optimizer will *consider it* for use - but it might still go another way if that's more convenient / faster.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering in the WHERE clause isn't relevant here.  So, yes, the two indexes will server all four examples perfectly well.

As for index to help JOINs, yes, there are *generally* advised.

You may find that if you create indexes that are perfect for every join you ever use, you have a lot of indexes.  This can lead to performance issues when writing to the table.  In such cases you may find a small set of indexes which are non-perfect for your JOINs and WHERE clauses, but are good enough that you can manage with just those few.  It's a compromise you need to balance yourself.

Finally, do note that some RDBMS *can* use index merging.  This may mean multiple simple or simpler indexes are nearly as good as a compound/covering index.  But in most cases you do need to consider both the WHERE clause and the JOINs, at the same time, when considering what to index.

This is because the main characteristic of an index is the order of the records.  The ideal scenario is to have all records of interest in one sequential block (after your WHERE clause and JOINs have filtered it down), and in an order friendly to subsequent JOINs or GROUP BYs.  In reality you aim such that the data is in as few sequential clusters as possible, and as best fit an order as possible.  Then let the RDBMS optimiser do the rest :)